# Is „Hochsee tauglich“ wrong?

Tags: spelling

On [phoenix.de](http://www.phoenix.de/content/phoenix/die_sendungen/dokumentationen/sphinx_gefangen_im_reich_des_shogun/12581) it reads:

> Adams lernt schnell Japanisch, baut für den Shogun **Hochsee taugliche Schiffe**, avanciert zum außenpolitischen Berater und wird später engster Vertrauter Ieyasus.

Is the bolded part correct? Or would you have to concatenate „Hochsee“ and „tauglich“?

- „Hochsee-tauglich“?
- „hochsee-tauglich“?

If they have to be concatenated, is the hyphen optional? If so, would „Hochseetauglich“ and/or „hochseetauglich“ be correct?

Comment: Besides, this kind of fault is called "Deppenleerzeichen" or Leerzeichen in Komposita (lit. spaces in composites), as it is quite widely used. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leerzeichen_in_Komposita

Comment: Actually the sentence as written is correct, assuming the Shogun is named "Hochsee", and Adams builds "taugliche Schiffe" for him. :-)

Comment: @celtschk: Hehe, that's true ☺

Answer (score 14):

The correct spelling is *hochseetauglich*. Actually, when using the hyphen to stress something, it should be **Hochsee-tauglich* because the capitalization of the noun would shine through - and that is horrible, please avoid it (cf. these discussions about [Ball-tauglich](http://www.neue-rechtschreibung.net/2010/02/19/warum-ist-ein-ball-taugliches-kleid-orthografisch-untauglich/) and [Marx-freundlich](http://www.neue-rechtschreibung.net/2010/03/19/von-marx-freundlichen-und-marxfreundlichen-ideologien/)).

Of course a different formulation might be "Das Schiff ist *für die Hochsee* tauglich".

Answer (score 5):

It is a compositum:

> hochseetauglich

Since it is an adjective (not a noun) its first letter is lower case (if it is not the first word of a sentence).

The hyphen is optional, but the word is short enough (for a german word) to avoid the hyphen.

Comment: Der Bindestrich ist nicht optional sondern wäre fehl am Platze und dessen Einsetzbarkeit korreliert auch nicht mit der Wortlänge.

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen is optional - use it when you want to amplify the meaning. For instance when there are „nicht-hochsee-taugliche“ ships as well. Anyway „hochseetauglich“ would be the most common way to write it.

Comment: I'd use "nicht-hochseetaugliche Schiffe" in that case, because "nicht-hochsee-tauglich" sounds to me as if the ships were fit for the non-open sea, instead of not being fit for the open sea, what clearly is meant here. Although, thinking again about it, I'd actually write "nicht hochseetaugliche Schiffe" without hyphen.

Comment: @celtschk It's the old ambiguity between Mädchen-Handelsschule and Mädchenhandels-Schule ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Es ist sehr schwer sich einen Text vorzustellen, bei dem aus dem Kontext nicht klar wird, um welche Form der Mädchenhandelsschule es sich handelt.

Comment: @userunknown: "Das Kalifat Ali ibn Fantasia, dessen Alleinherrscher in der Vergangenheit bereits mit plötzlichen Entscheidungen Schlagzeilen machte, verkündete gestern seine Pläne zur Eröffnung einer Mädchenhandelsschule. Auslöser ist die steigende Anzahl unverheirateter junger Frauen, für die es durch das traditionalistische Bildungswesen des konservativ geprägten Landes wenige Perspektiven für eine eigenständige Existenz gibt. Der amerikanische Außenminister sagte im Hinblick auf die Ankündigung, das Kalifat habe sich nun endgültig entschieden, ...

Comment: ... auf welche Seite es sich im Kampf gegen Terror, Sklavenhandel und Unterdrückung stelle. Der Bundesaußenminister gab sich zurückhaltender und brachte zum Ausdruck, es müsse sich in Zukunft erst noch zeigen, inwieweit reine Akündigungen in die Tat umgesetzt würden. Letztendlich könne auch diplomatischer Druck aus der westlichen Welt eine vorübergehende Wirkung haben." Und, weißt du nun, um welche Art der Mädchenhandelsschule es sich handelt? ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ein schönes, liebevoll konstruiertes Beispiel. Wenn man aber die Diskussion um diese Mädchenhandelsschule schon länger verfolgt hätte, dann wüsste man es. Ebenso, wenn die Äußerungen dazu etwas mehr Fleisch hätten. :)