# Englisch Kurs, Englischer Kurs, or Englischkurs

Tags: grammaticality

What's the difference between the three expressions above? I'm pretty sure that "Englisch Kurs" is right, since I've seen it before, but are the others wrong? If yes why?

And what about "Sprach Schule"? Is that right too? Or should it be Sprachschule?

Answer (score 13):

**Englischkurs** is correct.

If I read an offer for an `Englisch Kurs` I would think I get lessons from a native English  speaker, because the title seems to be defined by somebody who speaks English - not by somebody who speaks German.

*Englischer Kurs* sounds grammatically correct, but it does not mean language lesson. You may use it, if a school offers lessons in English and French. Then you have an *englischer Kurs* and a *französischer Kurs*. Or maybe you have a cooking lesson in English and French. Then you may say *englischer Kurs* to explain which lesson you mean.

*Sprachschule* is correct, *Sprach Schule* is not correct.

Comment: It seems to me there is an on-going tendency to separate compound nouns with spaces, and sometimes these words are joined back together again with hyphens ("English-Kurs"). In my physics course, I often see words such as 'Planck-Konstante' or 'Quanten Theorie"; I suppose it is especially common with technical or newly-coined terms and with people who can also speak English.

Comment: I think, the problem with the use of spaces within compound nouns is that people “copy” from English terms. But that does not mean that it is correct.      “Quantenmechanik” is correct. “Quanten Mechanik” is not. You can, however, use a hyphen to connect two nouns. This makes a lot of sense if the compound noun would be very long as the hyphen may help to make the word easier to grasp.

Comment: Es kann hilfreich sein um die Erfassung wie in Ur-Instinkt zu vereinfachen. Heute hatte ich kurz Schwierigkeiten das Wort Wachaumarathon zu identifizieren. Wachau-Marathon wäre hier hilfreich gewesen. Kombinationen unterschiedlicher Sprachen wie Back-Shop sind auch mit Bindestrich leichter erkennbar.

Answer (score 3):

*Englisch Kurs* is wrong. It contains a so-called Deppenleerzeichen. Correct is *Englischkurs*.

See the relevant Wikipedia article: [Leerzeichen in Komposita](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leerzeichen_in_Komposita)

It’s an error you’ll see very often. Collections of photos are [at Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/groups/deppenleerzeichen/) and [this blog](http://deppenleerzeichen.de/).

Related questions:

- [Deppen Leer Zeichen](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2383/1859)
- [Wie verwendet man Bindestriche bei mehrteiligen Eigennamen richtig?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/794/1859)
- [Is „Hochsee tauglich“ wrong?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/5440/1859)

Comment: +1 for all the internal refererences :)